# SQL Server Unique Index on (all) NON-NULL row values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I push related data. It has 6 columns that are nullable. Based on some logic, a combination of 2 is always non-null *(1st + one of last 4 & 2nd + one of last 4)*. This way I avoided having 8 different tables to hold the data.

Is there any T-SQL *(begin rather new to SQL Server specifics)* shortcut to create a unique key on these 6 columns that says ensure that any non-null combination among columns mentioned in the index *(1st - 6th)* is unique without begin really specific?

I can create unique indexes for each combination but I was wondering if there's any shortcut to stay lazy and use *(write)* 1 index vs. 8 of them. It's obviously not a big effort but anything shorter is better... in code, most of the times!

Comment: Having null columns just so you can avoid creating the proper tables is a bad design, and just one of the consequences is that you need to add checks and constraints to avoid bad values. Create a proper design instead. If you want to read data from all tables at once, use a view with a union

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know it's bad design but 8 tables make SqlServer's life easier while 1 makes mine. And given the fact that the table is 99% readonly and not that often visited... an easier life for me is a priority. ;)

Comment: Then why did you run into trouble? Actually, they make things *worse* both for the server and the programmer. SQL Server has some advanced features that could overcome the disadvantages, but in the end, you have to fix the design

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Had to make some changes and updating 8 tables... wasn't that much fun. So I combined them. I had built 8 initially... But updating 8 isn't fun. Especially DB + Code wise. :)

Comment: From your description is looks like you only need *two* tables with 4 nullable columns each. The first/second columns wouldn't be nullable and they would only appear in the first,second table respectively. If you explained what you are trying to do, you could simplify this even farther. Eg, if you use the nullable columns to enforce a single value selection from a flag or bitfield, you could use a lookup table and create only a single lookup column

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have foreign keys on them. Can't combine keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a computed column on something like:

```
COALESCE(
   cast(1 as binary(1)) + cast(col1 as binary(4)) /* Choose appropriate length for the type of col1 */
  ,cast(2 as binary(1)) + cast(col2 as binary(4)) /* Choose appropriate length for the type of col2 */
)
+ COALESCE(
   cast(3 as binary(1)) + cast(col3 as binary(4)) /* Choose appropriate length for the type of col3 */
  ,cast(4 as binary(1)) + cast(col4 as binary(4)) /* Choose appropriate length for the type of col4 */
  ,cast(5 as binary(1)) + cast(col5 as binary(4)) /* Choose appropriate length for the type of col5 */
  ,cast(6 as binary(1)) + cast(col6 as binary(4)) /* Choose appropriate length for the type of col6 */
  )
```

You might not need the first value in each pair - depending on whether (17,null,1,null,null,null) should be the same as (null,17,null,null,1,null) or not.

But anyway, with this computed column, you can put a unique index on it. :)

You could do this in two columns, but you can do it in a single one like this.

Comment: A filtered index would solve this. A better database design would be far better though

Comment: Then I think you should come up with a filtered index that would solve it... I think the index needs to be across all rows, so a filtered index doesn't solve it.

Comment: I wouldn't use a single table with nulls to "avoid" creating multiple tables in the first place. Avoids the problem entirely. From the description, it looks like only 2 tables are needed with the four nullable columns.

Comment: Sure, but people don't always get to choose what database deign they are dealing with.

Comment: If you check the question, the OP created this to avoid creating more tables

Comment: I think you answered my concern too. + between two binary is not addition but concatenation, right? What I don't know if computed columns are stored or computed when used? I mean does this binary result get cached or is calculated when necessary?

Comment: They would be created and stored in the index. Non-indexed computed columns are only created when the row is created if the column is marked as persisted.

Comment: And yes, binary(n) is concatenated, which is how I flagged which column was null, figuring (17,null) is different to (null,17) for columns 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks. I'll switch to this answer as it covers both uniqueness and prevents value collision.

Comment: And @PanagiotisKanavos, I know the OP created the tables, but that design might be fixed by now. So although it was chosen once, it might not be ideal now.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a check constraint to ensure that only one of the first two is set and one of the last 4.
2. Make a computed column `coalesce(c1, c2)` and a column `coalesce(c3, c4, c5, c6)`.
3. Make a unique index `(computed1, computed2)`.

I hope I got it right. Maybe you need to change this a little.

Comment: This is an excellent idea. I had the `CHECK` in place already. One problem is that values are numbers pointing to hash tables so they can collide. But I can write a solution with these computed columns *just need to add 2 more with a `case`* that hold number (1/2) for first non-null column and (3/4/5/6) for second non-null column. -- *I might have missed computed columns... it was worth asking the question. Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is, an index in SQL-Server is unique (On all rows in the index) or it is not unique.

Comment: For more reading on this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just create a unique index on the 6 columns

Comment: What about the null values? 6 columns, only 2 are non-null at any given time.

Comment: What about the null?  If two are not null and unique then add in 4 null and is it still unique.